# How to use Auth::login() without real authentication

Tags: laravel

I would like to use the "Laravel" Auth features.

I have a middleware which finds some data, extract :

```
$member = $this->memberService->getMemberRolesFromLdap($accessToken, $id);
```

$member is an array.

Just after this research, I would like to store this $member somewhere to retrieve some data later in some other classes. Like that :

```
$roles = Auth::user()->roles;
```

So I thought it was a good opportunity to use these Auth features. But for the moment, I have this error :

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, array given

So if I understand, I must declare somewhere that $member uses (or is) an instance of Authenticable. And there I admit my limits.

Is it a good idea to use Auth features to do that, and if so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this. It works, but I am not sure if it is best practice:

```
$ldapData = $this->memberService->getMemberRolesFromLdap($accessToken, $id);

    // login this member
    $user = new User();
    $user->ldapData = $ldapData;
    Auth::login($user);
```

And now, I can manipulate the user like that:

```
Auth::user()->ldapData
```